# Variables are always passed by value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 class `AuthManager`, `AuthView`. I want to load nib file of `AuthView` in implementation `AuthView` file (.m). 
I create a static method in `AuthView`:

```
+ (void)loadAuthView:(AuthView *)handle
{
  NSBundle * sdkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:
                          [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           URLForResource:SDK_BUNDLE_NAME withExtension:@"bundle"]];
  // handle == nil
  handle = [[sdkBundle loadNibNamed:AUTHVIEW_NIB_NAME owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
  // handle != nil
}
```

In `AuthManager`, I have a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AuthView * _authView;
```

And a method:

```
- (void)showAuthViewInView:(UIView *)view
{
  if (__authView == nil) {
    [AuthView loadAuthView:__authView];
    // __authView ( handle ) == nil ??????????????
  }

  [__authView showInView:view];
}
```

The problem: Inside of `loadAuthView`, `__authView` (`handle`) is != nil. But `__authView` is released after go outside of `loadAuthView`.

Question: Why does it happen? And how to keep `__authView` (`handle`) be not released?

And more, if I load nib in `AuthManager`, it works fine.

```
- (void)showAuthViewInView:(UIView *)view
{
  if (__authView == nil) {
    NSBundle * sdkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:
                            [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                             URLForResource:SDK_BUNDLE_NAME withExtension:@"bundle"]];
    __authView = [[sdkBundle loadNibNamed:AUTHVIEW_NIB_NAME owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
  }

  [__authView showInView:view];
}
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the handle in order for ARC to know the object is still referenced.

change `loadAuthView:` to

```
+ (AuthView *)loadAuthView
{
  NSBundle * sdkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:
                          [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           URLForResource:SDK_BUNDLE_NAME withExtension:@"bundle"]];
  // handle == nil
  AuthView *handle = [[sdkBundle loadNibNamed:AUTHVIEW_NIB_NAME owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
  // handle != nil
  return handle;
}
```

and

```
- (void)showAuthViewInView:(UIView *)view
{
  if (__authView == nil) {
    __authView = [AuthView loadAuthView];
  }

  [__authView showInView:view];
}
```

---

You are confused that variables are always passed by value (not reference). In your original code, modifying `handle` in `loadAuthView` will *not* modify the value of `__authView` because `handle` is a new copy of `__authView`. The only way to modify `__authView` is assign it directly using `=` operator (let's ignore pointer to pointer for now).

Here is a simple example:

```
void add(int b) {
  // b is 1
  b = b + 1;
  // b is 2
} // the value of b is discarded
int a = 1; // a is 1
add(a);
// a is still 1

void add2(int b) {
  return b + 1;
}
a = add2(a);
// a is 2 now
```

---

The other way to fix your original approach (not recommended) is using double pointer (`AuthView **`)

```
+ (void)loadAuthView:(AuthView **)handle
{
  NSBundle * sdkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:
                          [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           URLForResource:SDK_BUNDLE_NAME withExtension:@"bundle"]];
  *handle = [[sdkBundle loadNibNamed:AUTHVIEW_NIB_NAME owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
}
```

and

```
AuthView *authView; // make a local variable to avoid ARC issue
[AuthView loadAuthView:&authView];
__authView = authView;
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand about `void add(int b)`. But I pass `_authView ` is a pointer. And `handle = [[sdkBundle loadNibNamed...` will make `__authView` change?

Comment: You need to use double pointer to modify pointer. I have updated my answer to include an example of it.

Comment: I tried `[AuthView loadAuthView:&__authView];` and get error **Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back**

Comment: Anyway, `AuthView *handle = [[sdkBundle loadNibNamed:AUTHVIEW_NIB_NAME owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
  // handle != nil
  return handle;` works fine, thanks. But I just still confuse with parameter is a pointer. You can see `[__authView showInView:view];`, it works fine. In this method, I add `[view addSubview:self];`

Comment: Thats why I don't recommended to use it... I have fixed it.

Comment: You can modify the object but not the variable holds the object. If you assign `view` inside the method, the change is not visible outside the method.

Comment: They work fine. Thank you so much. But can you explain more about this case `[__authView showInView:view]` and `[AuthView loadAuthView:__authView];`, what is the different, between parameter pointers